# Numpy arange with spesific datetime given by month interval

Tags: arrays, numpy, datetime, date-range

I want to make array of datetime given by interval of months. It easy if I use days as interval like this

```
xyz = np.arange(np.datetime64('2020-03-24'), 3)
xyz
```

OUTPUT

```
array(['2020-03-24', '2020-03-25', '2020-03-26'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

It only incremental by 3 dyas. How about 3 months? I have tried this way and ERROR

```
np.arange(datetime('2020-03-28'), np.timedelta64(3,'M'))
```

I have tried this and Giving wrong result

```
np.arange(np.datetime64("2020-03-24"), np.datetime64("2020-06-24"), 
          np.timedelta64(1, 'M'), 
          dtype='datetime64[M]').astype('datetime64[D]')
```

OUTPUT

```
array(['2020-03-01', '2020-04-01', '2020-05-01'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `arange` without the `dtype` raises an error:

```
In [91]: x = np.arange(np.datetime64("2020-03-24"), np.datetime64("2020-06-24"),  
    ...:           np.timedelta64(1, 'M'))                                                     
...
TypeError: Cannot get a common metadata divisor for NumPy datetime metadata [M] and [D] because they have incompatible nonlinear base time units
```

Stepping by one month is not the same as stepping by n days.

With the dtype:

```
In [85]: x = np.arange(np.datetime64("2020-03-24"), np.datetime64("2020-06-24"),  
    ...:           np.timedelta64(1, 'M'),  
    ...:           dtype='datetime64[M]')                                                      
In [86]: x                                                                                     
Out[86]: array(['2020-03', '2020-04', '2020-05'], dtype='datetime64[M]')
```

The end points have been converted to month (without any implied date).

Note that the differences are the expected `1 month`:

```
In [87]: np.diff(x)                                                                            
Out[87]: array([1, 1], dtype='timedelta64[M]')
```

If I convert the dates to `D` dtype, it chooses the start of the month:

```
In [89]: x.astype('datetime64[D]')                                                             
Out[89]: array(['2020-03-01', '2020-04-01', '2020-05-01'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

The date time delta is no longer uniform:

```
In [90]: np.diff(x.astype('datetime64[D]'))                                                    
Out[90]: array([31, 30], dtype='timedelta64[D]')
```

===

Instead of `astype`, you could add the appropriate timedelta:

```
In [96]: x + np.array(3, 'timedelta64[D]')                                                     
Out[96]: array(['2020-03-04', '2020-04-04', '2020-05-04'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Comment: Thx for answer, The x was 24th march, but in the last result, it gives 4th days of each month. Any sugestion?

Comment: that's because I added a 3 day delta.  Choose your own.